# actionscript sound capturing

Tags: actionscript-3

I wrote something to capture sound from my microphone. I can visualise the sound data with `SoundMixer.computeSpectrum`.

My problem:

is there a way to mute the sound and still get sound data from `SoundMixer.computeSpectrum`?
Now I have this:

```
sc=son.play();
   var t:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0, 0);
   sc.soundTransform = t;
```

but I do not get any data. if I pump up the volume, data comes through again
(I need to mute it because it will echo otherwise).

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Hiiya,

Not sure if you get the I went around the SoundMixer.computeSpectrum, but you can get the mic.activityLevel:

```
            //var sound:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0); //not (0,0)
```

Comment: thx for the reply, but it still mutes the Sound class so I do not have any data coming in Soundspectrum .. would there be a way to mute the physical speakers of the machine? Or do I just have to warn users to mute their speakers..